# How to get the vm sub-folder object using pyvmomi to deploy virtual machine

Tags: python, pyvmomi

A sample datacenter ("DC1") hierarchy structure is given below, under DC1 there are two parent folders "Parent1" and "Parent2". Under them there are sub-folders containing VMs. I have to deploy the ovf under the correct sub-folder under the given parent path. For instance, I have to deploy it under subfolder2 of Parent1 and not under Parent2.

*Folder input*: **parent1/subfolder1/subfolder2**

```
DC1
|
|----Parent1
|    |---subfolder1
|           |---subfolder2
|
|----Parent2
|    |---subfolder2
```

Current code searches for the first available folder name from the datacenter folder objects' list without following the directory structure.

```
from pyvim.connect import SmartConnect, Disconnect
import ssl
try:
    #context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
    #context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
    context = ssl._create_unverified_context()
    si = SmartConnect(host=args.host,
                      user="root",
                      pwd="****",
                      port=int("443"),
                      sslContext=context)
except:
    raise Exception("Unable to connect")

datacenter = connect.content.rootFolder.childEntity[0]

vmfolder_list = datacenter.vmFolder.childEntity
for vmfolder in vmfolder_list:
    if vmfolder.name == search_folder:
        return vmfolder
raise Exception("Unable to find object by the name of %s in list:\n%s" %
         (search_folder, map(lambda x: x.name, vmfolder_list)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by using the below solution:

```
def getFolderObj(parent, search_folder):
    for folder in self.content.viewManager.CreateContainerView(parent, [vim.Folder], True).view:
        if folder.name == search_folder:
            return folder
    return None
vmfolder_obj = datacenter.vmFolder
for search_folder in "Parent1/subfolder1/subfolder2".split(os.path.sep):
    if vmfolder_obj and search_folder:
        vmfolder_obj = getFolderObj(vmfolder_obj, search_folder)
    else:
        break
if vmfolder_obj == None:
    raise Exception("Folder resource not found!")
```